# Image URL not entering into a Vue component?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vue-component, vue-props

I am trying to make a vue tag component and I'm not able to throw the source to the template

**html**

```html
<card 
  aposter="assets\images\poster.png" 
  aname="a title"> </card>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
Vue.component('card', {
  props: ['aposter', 'aname'],
  template: `
    <div>
    <img src="{{aposter}}"/>
      <br>
      <p>{{ aname }}</p>
    </div>
  `
})
```

but the img src executes as: *src="{{aposter}}"* and not putting the actual link to the image

I tried to fix it alot I don't seem to find anything what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have to **bind** the src attribute

Change your template:

```
    Vue.component('card', {
      props: ['aposter', 'aname'],
      template: `
        <div>
        <img :src="aposter"/>
          <br>
          <p>{{ aname }}</p>
        </div>
      `
    })
```

This will bind src attribute to the aposter prop.
You can read more about binding in Vue here: [Vue Template Syntax](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Attributes)

`:src` is a shorthand for `v-bind:src`